# Need a suggestion on error handling in partial views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0, razor

I can't seem to find an answer to this. Basically, inside of a View, I got

```
@{
    Html.RenderAction("PartialViewAction", "SomeController");
}
```

Let's say, this partial action throws an exception: DB connection is out, or whatever. How would I display the error to the user?

All articles/blogs that I see talk about error handling in (non-partial) Views and partials rendered on AJAX calls.  But this case is neither.

Comment: "Let's say, this partial action throws an exception: DB connection is out, or whatever" - you could do your db access, or whatever action can throw an exception, in the controller.  Then pass a ViewModel to the View, which won't throw an exception unless there is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think each view should handle their exceptions, so your logic should be in the view, but if we keep in mind MVC rules, exception handling should be on controllers, because they are in charge of communicating with the model. So the question is how make them show in the final view. I don't know if this could be helpful, but I will try a workaround.

The idea is subscribe your exceptions during a request in a list for example, an elegant solution could be having this list in your Viewbag, and then in your global layout write them in the view for example

```
<ul name="hiddenExceptions" class="hidden">
     <li>exception 1 message wrote in the layout</li>
     <li>exception 2</li>
</ul>
```

You can have an script later that iterates through this list an take appropriate actions, show them in a box, show at the top of the page, etc.

Hope it helps

Comment: Not bad for error displaying, I guess.  But, what would I do with the partial view?  It can't be displayed, because it errored out.  Let's say, if view model is null as a result of the error.  Would I just display empty HTML elements and in the error list say something like the data should've been there, but too bad it's not? :)

Comment: what about if you add another elements to the exception list in your partial view, you can access the ViewBag there